# Passing down value

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass `this.props.item` down so I can perform some actions with it however I've been unable to do so, it's giving me the error: `Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters`. It's running through an array so it actually has the value

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(this.props.item) => {
  //Do something with value here
 }}
>
```

I also tried this way unluckily

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.item => {
  //Do something with value here
 }}
>
```

What's the correct way to write this please?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting: Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters

Comment: for readability reasons you should better use it like that : onPress={this._functionName} and do your stuff in _functionName

Comment: Wouldn't `onPress` pass the event as the argument to the function? `onPress={(event) => {`, maybe then get the value of the component with `event.currentTarget.value`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
  console.log(this.props.item)
 }}
>
```